# Typo3 tt-news categories

Tags: typo3

My client wants to update an old tt-news installation version 2.x. Unfortunately the former maintainer of the site quit the job and let me do his job and although there is a huge category tree of news none of the categories are selected in the plugin configuration dialog at several locations. This seems to work with an older Typo3 4.1.3 but not when I update to a newer version. My question is it possible the tell tt-news with Typoscript or with a constant the current news category and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plugin.tt_news {
  categorySelection = 2,3
  # show only selected categories
  categoryMode = 1
}
```

Details about this: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.1.0/view/1/4/

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem, instead the starting point is used to display news.